# Consuming Delphi web service with Custom SOAP Headers using WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, delphi, soap, wcf-client

We need to consume a third party web service (written in Delphi) using WCF. The problem that we have come up against is that the Delphi service is RPC/Encoded, and it uses custom SOAP Headers. If we add the following to our ServiceContract (to deal with the RPC encoding):

```
[XmlSerializerFormat(Style = OperationFormatStyle.Rpc,
    Use = OperationFormatUse.Encoded)]
```

we get an error saying that this can't be done in conjunction with MessageContracts with headers.

```
Message *** must not have headers to be used in RPC encoded style
```

Does anyone know a way around this?

Thanks